# Draw new tetrominos in JavaScript tetris

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, tetris

I'm trying to draw tetrominos in JavaScript and I'm having some trouble. I think the code I have, this.blocks = i.blocks[b][c], is incorrect, but it may be more. Now that my eyes have started hurting, I've decided to ask for help. Does this.blocks = i.blocks[b][c] not work because this.blocks can't store an array? Or is there another problem. Thank you for your help.

Here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8aS9E/

Here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        var h = canvas.height;
        var w = canvas.width;
        var gridWidth = w / 4;
        var gridHeight = h;
        var cols = gridWidth / 10; //width, columns
        var rows = cols; //height, rows
        window.addEventListener("keydown", test, true); 
        var b = 0;
        var c = 0;

    var gravity = 0;

    var id;
    var type = 2;
    var color; 
    var x = gridWidth * 2;
    var y = -30;
    var position;
    var velocityY;
    var tetrominoId = 0;
  var i = { id: 'i', size: 4, 
                blocks: [[0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0]], 
                color: 'cyan'   };

function tetromino(id, type, color, position, y, velocityY){
    this.id = i.id;
    this.blocks = i.blocks[b][c];
    this.color = i.color;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocityY = 1;
}

var tetrominoList = [];

function addTetromino(type, color, position, x, y, velocityY){
tetrominoList[tetrominoId] = new tetromino(tetrominoId, type, color, x, y, velocityY);
tetrominoId++;

}

function tetrominoDraw(){

        tetrominoList.forEach(function(tetromino){

        for(b = 0; b < 4; b++){

            for(c = 0; c < 4; c++){



                    ctx.fillStyle = tetromino.color;
                    ctx.fillRect(
                        gridWidth * 2 + tetromino.blocks[b][c] * 
                        b * cols, tetromino.blocks[b][c] * c * rows + gravity + y,
                        cols, rows
                        );
                    ctx.fill();
                }   
            }
        }   
        });

        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tetromino.blocks isn't an array but an integer because it's equal to the value of the first element of the first array of i.blocks (i.blocks[0][0] because both b and c variables are defined as zeros in their initializations).

All you have to do is get rid of an array address in the tetromino declaration:

```
function tetromino(id, type, color, position, y, velocityY) {
    this.id = i.id;
    this.blocks = i.blocks;
    this.color = i.color;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velocityY = 1;
}
```

I've updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8aS9E/1/